# How do you convert a Future to a js.Promise in Scala.js?

Tags: scala.js

Since JavaScript doesn't have Futures (at least, not as a standard, as far as I know) but `Future`s are very prevalent in Scala code (including mine), it would be great to know how to convert from `Future[A]` to a `js.Promise[A]` when providing APIs in for consumption in JavaScript.

Is there an existing library function for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a library function for that.

```
import scala.scalajs.js.JSConverters._

val future: Future[A] = ...
val promise: js.Promise[A] = future.toJSPromise
```